# ReactJS and AJAX Uncaught TypeError: Cannot Read Property 'bugs' of Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making AJAX request inside of a React function while making references to the state in the React class. However, I'm getting a TypeError where the reference to the state is undefined when I enter the AJAX request.

Here's my code snippet, I"m unsure how to proceed here. Where am I losing context?

```
class BugList extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            bugs: [],
        };
    }
    addBug(bug) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', url: '/api/bugs', contentType: 'application/json', data:JSON.stringify(bug),
            success: function(data) {
                var bug = data;

                var bugsModified = this.state.bugs.concat(bug);
                this.setState({bugs: bugsModified});
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.log("error adding bug: ", err);
            }
        });
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        $.ajax('/api/bugs').done(function(data) {
            this.setState({bugs: data})
        }.bind(this));
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Bug Tracker</h1>
                <BugFilter />
                <hr />
                <BugTable bugs={this.state.bugs}/>
                <hr />
                <BugAdd addBug={this.addBug}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The problematic line in question:

```
var bugsModified = this.state.bugs.concat(bug);
```

The error log:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bugs' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `bind` the `addBug method`, use this:

```
<BugAdd addBug={this.addBug.bind(this)}/>
```

You are passing a method from parent component to child component, `bind` that `method` in parent component, like this:

```
<BugAdd addBug={this.addBug.bind(this)}/>
```

or you can define the `binding` in the `constructor` also, like this:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        bugs: [],
    };
   this.addBug = this.addBug.bind(this);
}
```

and use directly:

```
<BugAdd addBug={this.addBug}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

it is a scope issue, try..

```
addBug(bug) {
        ***var that = this;***
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', url: '/api/bugs', contentType: 'application/json', data:JSON.stringify(bug),
            success: function(data) {
                var bug = data;

                var bugsModified = ***that.state.bugs.concat(bug)***;
                this.setState({bugs: bugsModified});
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.log("error adding bug: ", err);
            }
        });
    }
```

or you can also try

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            bugs: [],
        };
    this.addbugs = this.addbugs.bind(this);
    }
```

and keep the rest as it was

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have bound the ajax success function you forgot to bind the `addBug` function

You can make use of arrow function to do that like

```
class BugList extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            bugs: [],
        };
    }
    addBug(bug) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', url: '/api/bugs', contentType: 'application/json', data:JSON.stringify(bug),
            success: function(data) {
                var bug = data;

                var bugsModified = this.state.bugs.concat(bug);
                this.setState({bugs: bugsModified});
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.log("error adding bug: ", err);
            }
        });
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        $.ajax('/api/bugs').done(function(data) {
            this.setState({bugs: data})
        }.bind(this));
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Bug Tracker</h1>
                <BugFilter />
                <hr />
                <BugTable bugs={this.state.bugs}/>
                <hr />
                <BugAdd addBug={(data) => this.addBug(data)}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```